# Automatically returning to pre-hover and pre-focus state for links

Tags: html, css, hover, focus

I have modified the default appearance of links by changing `a:hover` and `a:focus` for links under a specific category:

```
.myclass > a:hover, a:focus {
    color: limegreen;
}
```

Everything looks exactly as I want, except for one little behavior: when I open a link in a new tab, upon returning to the page I see that the link I clicked still shows the hover and focus style, even though the cursor is not on the link. I have to click elsewhere on the window (or even outside the browser window) to make it go away.

How can I make the link text/icon automatically return to their un-hovered unfocused state after the click by simply not having the cursor on the link?

I am hoping this can be done without resorting to JavaScript.

P.S. I am using Bootstrap v. 3.3.4.

<s>P.P.S. Already tried using `a:active`, but that did not help.</s>

Comment: use `:active` instesd `:focus`

Comment: is this is in all browsers?

Comment: @ATomCalledStu Yes, this is in browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a:active` instead `:focus`

```css
a:hover, a:active {
    color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">try me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `:active` selector as well:

```
a:active, a:focus, a:hover {
  color: limegreen;
}
```